# Abandoned planetary library foretells CDs

Tags: story-identification

Disclaimer: There are three or stories I have wondered about for years but until coming across this site I didn't think I could possibly find out what they were.  (This is the second post.) Since I probably read them as a teen plus or minus a decade they could all be from the 50s to the 80s, though probably in the earlier part of the range. No worries if no one has any thoughts.

So this is an old story about a star ship coming across an abandoned planet once home to an ancient civilization and finding a building with a vast room with countless slots in the walls holding disks with information which could be accessed by placing them on a single pedestal in the center of the room.  This is all I recall, and this could have been a chapter in a novel as well.

Comment: if the answer is as DavidW found, I wouldn't call these discs but merely fancier wax cylinders that would have already been known at the time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonograph_cylinder

Comment: This sounds like the "prayer fans" in _[Beyond the Blue Event Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Blue_Event_Horizon)_ (1980) by Frederik Pohl.

Comment: I recognized the space library from H. P. Lovecraft's [The_Shadow_Out_of_Time](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Shadow_Out_of_Time/full) but it didn't match after re-reading it. No star ships, nothing abandoned, no slots or disks.

Answer (score 7):

It's only a partial match, but the description of a wall of playable media in niches and a built-in player apparatus sounds like [*The Sleeper Awakes*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?180320) (1910) by H.G. Wells.

(*The Sleeper Awakes* is a reprint of *When the Sleeper Wakes* from 1899, but it's the one I found at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/12163/12163-h/12163-h.htm).)

> He observed one entire side of the outer room was set with rows of peculiar double cylinders inscribed with green lettering on white that harmonized with the decorative scheme of the room, and in the centre of this side projected a little apparatus about a yard square and having a white smooth face to the room. A chair faced this. He had a transitory idea that these cylinders might be books, or a modern substitute for books, but at first it did not seem so.
>
> [...]
>
> He puzzled over this peculiar cylinder for some time and replaced it. Then he turned to the square apparatus and examined that. He opened a sort of lid and found one of the double cylinders within, and on the upper edge a little stud like the stud of an electric bell. He pressed this and a rapid clicking began and ceased. He became aware of voices and music, and noticed a play of colour on the smooth front face. He suddenly realised what this might be, and stepped back to regard it.

Comment: Wasn't there a similar thing in the (movie of the) "The time machine" where there data disk was a small disk that was played by spinning on its edge on the player?